# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in E:\Oficina\xampp\htdocs\Formulario-Oficina\listartecnicas.php on line 6

Tags: php, mysqli

i have this problem

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in E:\Oficina\xampp\htdocs\Formulario-Oficina\listartecnicas.php on line 6

and

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in E:\Oficina\xampp\htdocs\Formulario-Oficina\listartecnicas.php on line 25

this is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD811.png)

Comment: Can you paste your code instead of adding the image?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: You cannot just search/replace `mysql_` to `mysqli` and expect anything to work, no matter how many bozos on the internet claim that you can.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write $con at first like this.

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
```

The syntax is this
*mysqli_query(connection,query,resultmode);*